# If $f^2$ or $f^3\in \mathcal{R}$ on $[a,b]$. Does it follow that $f\in \mathcal{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a bounded real function on $[a,b]$, and $f^2\in \mathcal{R}$ on $[a,b]$. Does it follow that $f\in \mathcal{R}$?
Does the answer change if we assume that $f^3\in \mathcal{R}$?

**Proof:** 1. Let's take $f(x)=2D(x)-1$ where $D(x)$ is Dirichlet function then $f^2\in \mathcal{R}$ but $f\notin\mathcal{R}$.

Let's take a look at the following claim:

**Theorem:** Suppose $f\in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$, $m\leqslant f\leqslant M$, $\phi$ is continuous on $[m,M]$, and $h(x)=\phi(f(x))$ on $[a,b]$. Then $h\in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$

**2.** Suppose  $f^2\in \mathcal{R}$  on $[a,b]$, $0\leqslant f^2\leqslant M$. Taking $\phi(x)=\sqrt{x}$ which is continuous at $[0,M]$ we get that $\phi(f(x))=\sqrt{f^2(x)}=|f(x)|\in \mathcal{R}$.

Remark: If $f(x)$ is non-negative on $[a,b]$ we would got that $f(x)\in \mathcal{R}$. But in our above example function $f(x)$ taking both negative and positive values.

**3.** Suppose  $f^3\in \mathcal{R}$  on $[a,b]$, $m\leqslant f^3\leqslant M$. Taking $\phi(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ which is continuous at $[m,M]$ we get that $\phi(f(x))=\sqrt[3]{f^3(x)}=f(x)\in \mathcal{R}$.

Are my reasonings correct? Because I'm not entirely sure at them.

Comment: That looks correct to me. Regarding the last point, indeed the cubic root is defined on all $\mathbb R$ and is continuous.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, Thanks for checking!

Comment: If the theorem you quote is known to you and you may use it, your solution is very nice. Otherwise, you should prove it.

Comment: @PhoemueX, I know that theorem. I read it couple days ago in Rudin PMA Chapter 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. For completeness, I note that there is nothing special about $x^2$ and $x^3$; the same argument yields the following more general claims:

1. If $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and strictly monotone, then   Riemann integrability of $\phi\circ f$ implies Riemann integrability of $f$ on the same interval $[a,b]$.
2. If $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is not injective, then there is a function $f$ that fails to be Riemann  integrable on $[a,b]$, while $\phi\circ f$ is Riemann integrable  on $[a,b]$.